# limit of $n^2(\frac{1+n}{3n})^n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I want to determine the limit of this succession, for this I suppose that  $$n^2(\frac{n}{3n})^n≤n^2(\frac{1+n}{3n})^n≤n^2(\frac{2n}{3n})^n$$

And as $n^2(\frac{2n}{3n})^n$ and $n^2(\frac{n}{3n})^n$ converge to $0$, then by the squeeze theorem $n^2(\frac{1+n}{3n})^n$ also does

Is this true?
Any help is appreciated

Comment: There are $n^2$ factors missing on the left and right sides, no?

Comment: That's right, I'm going to correct

Comment: Is that the $n\to\infty$ limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This first comment no longer applies, the post was edited**

Your second inequality is not correct. Take for example $n=2$. Then

$$n^2\left(\frac{1+n}{3n}\right)^n=1, \quad \left(\frac{2n}{3n}\right)^n=\frac{4}{9},$$

and clearly $1\geq \frac{4}{9}$.

**This is still relevant**

What you could do, however, is notice that you can rewrite it as

$$n^2\left(\frac{1+n}{3n}\right)^n=n^2 \left(\frac{1}{3n}+\frac{1}{3}\right)^n=\frac{n^2}{3^n} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n.$$

Now notice that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2}{3^n}=0$$

(I will assume you already know this), and

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=e.$$

Thus if you take the limit, you can split it up into a product of limits, and what you end up with is

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n^2\left(\frac{1+n}{3n}\right)^n=0\cdot e=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

You have $n^2\left(\frac{1+n}{3n}\right)^n=\frac{n^2}{3^n}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$.

It is well-known that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ converges to $e$ and it can be shown that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2}{3^n}=0$ (for example, by using L'hospital's Rule twice).

Therefore, $\lim_{n\to\infty} n^2\left(\frac{1+n}{3n}\right)^n=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $n>1.$

$0<n^2 \left (\dfrac{1+n}{3n}\right)^n <n^2\left(\dfrac{2n}{3n}\right) ^n=$

$n^2\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^n = \dfrac{n^2}{a^n}$, where $a:=3/2>1.$

Take the limit.